# compatibility of tensorflow and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow as a machine learning library and hadoop as a big data framework.
But i don know these are compatible.
I can't search any reference in website.

my question is

1. Can I use tensorflow with hadoop?
2. (if no) please recommend big data framework can be use with tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are compatible. In my company we have application running on Hadoop using TensorFlow. To make it clear think of TensorFlow as python library which can be used within python. One example will be to write a Map-Reduce code in which mapper groups/accumulates data and in reducer your learning code is present in reducer using TensorFlow.

Comment: Thank you. I could be cleared this problem for your answer.